# How to get the selected value from the select in PHP?

Tags: php, forms

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
 {  
    echo "
        <form method='POST' action='booking_feed.php'>
        <tr class=responstable>
            <td>
               <select name='from' style=width:90%>
                    <option value=$row[beginning]>$row[beginning]</option>
                    <option value=$row[ms1]>$row[ms1]</option>
                    <option value=$row[ms2]>$row[ms2]</option>
                    <option value=$row[ms3]>$row[ms3]</option>
                    <option value=$row[end]>$row[end]</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name='to' style=width:90%>
                    <option value=$row[ms1]>$row[ms1]</option>
                    <option value=$row[ms2]>$row[ms2]</option>
                    <option value=$row[ms3]>$row[ms3]</option>
                    <option value=$row[end]>$row[end]</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ";
    $i++;
 }
```

My other file named booking_feed.php is as follows, I am getting the value of the last option in return of `$_POST['from']/$_POST['to']` irrespective of whichever option I choose.

```
 <?php
 $from=$_POST['from'];
 $to=$_POST['to'];
 echo $from.$to;
 ?>
```

Comment: you are missing tons of quotes and braces. hint :`<option value=\"{$row['ms1']}\">{$row['ms1']}</option>`

Comment: you get the last answer, because in your `from` and `to` the `while` will save just the last result. You need an `from[]` and `to[]`.

Comment: i not even think you get any data from that syntax

Comment: and you are looping this <form method='POST' action='booking_feed.php'> without having </form> in you loop and like @Edwin said you need [] behind your input names to make it a array then for retrieval you need to count the posts and retrieve it like that

Comment: Do some stackoverflow man, before posting

Comment: @YadavChetan I am actually new to **stackoverflow** and I did not have much time for studying the stackoverflow that's why the post got a bit disorganised. Will  try to improve on it next time around.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){  
  echo "<form method='POST' action='booking_feed.php'>
  <tr class=responstable>
  <td><select name='from[]' style=width:90%>
    <option value=$row[beginning]>$row[beginning]</option>
    <option value=$row[ms1]>$row[ms1]</option>
    <option value=$row[ms2]>$row[ms2]</option>
    <option value=$row[ms3]>$row[ms3]</option>
    <option value=$row[end]>$row[end]</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td><select name='to[]' style=width:90%>
    <option value=$row[ms1]>$row[ms1]</option>
    <option value=$row[ms2]>$row[ms2]</option>
    <option value=$row[ms3]>$row[ms3]</option>
    <option value=$row[end]>$row[end]</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
";
$i++;
}
```

and then

```
<?php
   $i=0;
   foreach($_POST['from'] as $from){
     echo $from.$_POST['to'][$i];
     $i++;
  }
?>
```

this is just an example, you can adjust it as you wish.

As a tip I would use the HEREDOC or NOWDOC.

Comment: Thanks Edwin! But I've one more problem that the values which I have assigned into the options of the select tags also contain spaces and when I am retrieving those values then only the first word is returned, can you please help me out on that too? It'll be a great help.

Comment: try with the HEREDOC instead of multiline.